# Reading or listening to audio books

Tags: books, reading

What's better, reading a book or listening to audio books?
I've done a bit research, and most places say that on isn't superior to the other.
But I'm not convinced by that, since I don't see the logic in it.

Reading a book teaches you how to read faster plus you get the information about what you're reading.
Listening to a book only gets the information about what you're reading, but doesn't improve the reading skill.

When that has been said, listening does have the advantage of only occupying your ears and not both your eyes and hands, so you can to some other task while getting the information.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You haven't (explicitly) considered whether you can absorb information faster by reading or listening.

Comment: I believe reading is faster, since you don't have to pronounce each word in your head. When listening, each word has to be pronounced.

Comment: There are studies on how much content you can remember after listening, reading, etc. ... If I remember correctly, reading beats listening.

Comment: "Better" for what?

Comment: In general, it is a mistake to claim that one particular method of learning is better than another **for all students**.  Usually, one method is better for some but not for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not really formulated well - there is no better or worse. A better question title would be something like "What are the advantages and disadvantages of reading books vs listening to audiobooks?". Reading books is better if hands and eyes are free; as you tend to be more immersed in the medium, you probably retain more information. Most likely there is academic literature along these lines.

Audiobooks are a great invention. Whoever commutes by car to their job can benefit from having at least **one extra hour** of reading per day. That is probably just as much as an avid reader reads on an average day. While it is true that you can read a book much faster than someone else can spell it out loud, that is time you can't recover with regular books. Also, if the audiobook is not in your native language, then it can become a powerful instrument in understanding that language's pronunciation.

Comment: Ok, so neither reading or listening improves a skill that the other one doesn't? Because I could imagine that reading improves a skill while listening does not.

Comment: Caveat: my answer is based on personal experience, not on academic research. Reading a lot sure makes you read faster. But reading a lot in order to read faster is the goal of reading when you are 6 year old. An adult reads in order to learn more about something, or be entairtened.

Comment: It is true that an adult reads to learn more. But reading faster also means learning faster.

Comment: Agree. I think you should rephrase the question as something like "what are the advantages and disadvantages of reading books vs listening to audiobooks"

Comment: @DeadlyCow - reading a physics textbook faster is unlikely to result in learning the physics faster, much less learning it at all.

Comment: That made me laugh. Indeed, for technical books, the slower, the better. On the other hand, learning physics via audiobooks - that would require somebody with incredible abstraction and math visualisation skills :D

Comment: Yes, that is true. But I guess that comes down to preferences. I'd prefer to read physics multiple times than to listening to it. That is a good point. And yes, I should probably rephrase the question. But I think I roughly got my question answered